# How to make a Clustered Service send traffic on the Virtual IP

Tags: c#, cluster-computing, failovercluster

I have a windows service written in C# that communicates with an FTP Server. We have recently added the service as a "Generic Service" on a Failover Cluster running on Windows 2008 R2. The "Generic Service" has its own Virtual IP address.

When the FTP connection is initiated, the source IP address is that of the NODE hosting the service and not the Virtual IP. Its been suggested that if the service were "Cluster Aware", then the source IP would be the virtualIP.

We are trying to avoid adding the IP address of every node in the cluster to the ACL of FTP Server. I am looking for a programmatic solution to cause the service to use the virtual ip for outbound traffic in a clustered environment.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with C# or programming?

Comment: The service is written in C#. I'm the programmer, and I'm looking for a programmatic solution. Such as tapping into the clusterapi, and setting the source ip... thats why I tagged it they way I did.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify.